# Number of gray codes on a constellation

Tags: combinatorics

I wonder how many binary gray codes exists for a constellation?

A constellation is a set of points in 2D-space, and as mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constellation_diagram, there is a corresponding gray code (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).

At the time, I am only interested in circular and square constellation of size $2^k$ points for an arbitrary $k$.

My first guess was $n\log(n)!$, since there is a permutation possible and where the zero is, was proven wrong by exhaustive counting of circular constellation of size 8 (PSK8), which have 96 gray codes.

If anyone can prove it or give a counter example on the square for this formula, it would be very good.